# Editing a .csv file with a batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

this is my first question on here. I work as a meteorologist and have some coding experience, though it is far from professionally taught. Basically what I have is a .csv file from a weather station that is giving me data that is too detailed. (65.66 degrees and similar values) What I want to do is automate a way via a script file that would access the .csv file and get rid of values that were too detailed. (Take a temp from 65.66 to 66 (rounding up for anything above .5 and down for below) or for a pressure (29.8889) and making it (29.89) using the same rounding rules.) Is this possible to be done? If so how should I go about it. Again keep in mind that my coding skills for batch files are not the strongest.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I think your options for using batch files for rounding are some what limited/non-existent.  Have you got access to [powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)? or [cscript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx)? Or some other scripting engine?

Comment: Question is too broad for SO. Note that CMD is way too limited to parse CSV files in sensible way. You may want to look into existing tools (Excel?) or better languages. JavaScript/Powershell if you want to stick with raw Windows tools, maybe Bash is you have latest Insider build of Win10, or any other language out there. Note: for future questions please avoid "new here"/"thank you" text as it usually does not directly relate to the problem.

Comment: Batch is wrong language.

Comment: Your rounding is inconsistent; temperature gets rounded to an integer, but pressure gets two decimal places? Also, _what does your csv file look like_? I can't even begin to start working on this without knowing where things are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments above.  Math in batch is limited to integers, and won't work well for the manipulations you want.

I'd use PowerShell. Besides easily handling floating point math, it also has built-in methods for objectifying CSV data (as well as XML and other types of structured data).  Take the following hypothetical CSV data contained within `weather.csv`:

```perl
date,time,temp,pressure,wx
20160525,12:30,65.66,30.1288,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
20160525,13:00,67.42,30.3942,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
20160525,13:30,68.92,31.0187,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
20160525,14:00,70.23,30.4523,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
20160525,14:30,70.85,29.8889,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
20160525,15:00,69.87,28.7384,GHCND:US1TNWS0001
```

The first thing you want to do is import that data as an object (using `import-csv`), then round the numbers as desired -- temp rounded to a whole number, and pressure rounded to a precision of 2 decimal places.  Rounding to a whole number is easy.  Just recast the data as an integer.  It'll be rounded automatically.  Rounding the pressure column is pretty easy as well if you invoke the .NET [`[math]::round()`](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_math.htm) method.

```perl
# grab CSV data as a hierarchical object
$csv = import-csv weather.csv

# for each row of the CSV data...
$csv | foreach-object {

    # recast the "temp" property as an integer
    $_.temp = [int]$_.temp

    # round the "pressure" property to a precision of 2 decimal places
    $_.pressure = [math]::round($_.pressure, 2)
}
```

Now pretend you want to display the temperature, barometric pressure, and weather station name where "date" = 20160525 and "time" = 14:30.

```perl
$row = $csv | where-object { ($_.date -eq 20160525) -and ($_.time -eq "14:30") }
$row | select-object pressure,temp,wx | format-table
```

Assuming "pressure" started with a value of 29.8889 and "temp" had a value of 70.85, then the output would be:

```perl
pressure temp wx
-------- ---- --
   29.89   71 GHCND:US1TNWS0001
```

If the CSV data had had multiple rows with the same date and time values (perhaps measurements from different weather stations), then the table would display with multiple rows.

And if you wanted to export that to a new csv file, just replace the `format-table` cmdlet with `export-csv destination.csv`

```perl
$row | select-object pressure,temp,wx | export-csv outfile.csv
```

Handy as a pocket on a shirt, right?

---

Now, pretend you want to display the human-readable station names rather than NOAA's designations.  Make a hash table.

```perl
$stations = @{
    "GHCND:US1TNWS0001" = "GRAY 1.5 E TN US"
    "GHCND:US1TNWS0003" = "GRAY 1.9 SSE TN US"
    "GHCND:US1TNWS0016" = "GRAY 1.3 S TN US"
    "GHCND:US1TNWS0018" = "JOHNSON CITY 5.9 NW TN US"
}
```

Now you can add a "station" property to your "row" object.

```perl
$row = $row | select *,"station"
$row.station = $stations[$row.wx]
```

And now if you do this:

```perl
$row | select-object pressure,temp,station | format-table
```

Your console shows this:

```perl
pressure temp station
-------- ---- -------
   29.89   71 GRAY 1.5 E TN US
```

---

For extra credit, say you want to export this row data to JSON (for a web page or something).  That's slightly more complicated, but not impossibly so.

```perl
add-type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$JSON = new-object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

# convert $row from a PSCustomObject to a more generic hash table
$obj = @{}

# the % sign in the next line is shorthand for "foreach-object"
$row.psobject.properties | %{
    $obj[$_.Name] = $_.Value
}

# Now, stringify the row and display the result
$JSON.Serialize($obj)
```

The output of that should be similar to this:

```perl
{"station":"GRAY 1.5 E TN US","wx":"GHCND:US1TNWS0001","temp":71,"date":"201605
25","pressure":29.89,"time":"14:30"}
```

... and you can redirect it to a .json file by using `>` or pipe it into the `out-file` cmdlet.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I just defaulted to batch files as that was really the only place I knew to start. Is there a way to save commands for PowerShell to a file that could be scheduled and executed via the windows task scheduler?

Comment: @WXSquirrel Just save your PowerShell script with a .ps1 extension.  To execute it, do `powershell -ex bypass "C:\path\to\script.ps1"`.  The `-ex bypass` arguments override the default execution policy restrictions (if applicable).  It's shorthand for `-ExecutionPolicy bypass`.  [More info](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/).

Answer (score 2):

DOS batch scripting is, by far, not the best place to edit text files.  However, it is possible. I will include sample, incomplete DOS batch code at the bottom of this post to demonstrate the point.  I recommend you focus on Excel (no coding needed) or Python.

- Excel - You don't need to code at all with Excel.  Open the csv file.  Let's say you have 66.667 in cell B12. In cell C12 enter a formula using the round function (code below).  You can also teach yourself some Visual Basic for Applications.  But, for this simple task, that is overkill.  When done, if you save as csv format, you will loose your formulae and only have data.  Consider saving as xlsx or xlsm.
- Visual Basic Script - you can run vbscript on your    machine with
  cscript.exe (or    wscript.exe), which is part of  Windows.  But, if using VB script, you might as well use VBA in Excel.  It is almost identical.
- Python is a very high level    langauge with built in libraries
  that make editing a csv file super easy. I recommend Anaconda
  (a Python suite) from continuum.io. But, you can find the generic Python at
  python.org as well.  Anaconda will come prepackaged with lots of
  helpful libraries.  For csv editing, you will likely want to use the 
  pandas library.  You can find plenty of short videos on YouTube.

**Excel**

```
Say you have 66.667 in cell B12.  Set the formula in C13 to...
  "=ROUND(B12,0)" to round to integer
  "=ROUND(B12,1)" to round to one decimal place
As you copy and past, Excel will attempt to intelligently update the formulas for you.
```

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd  
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
# load csv file to memory. Name your columns "using names=[]"
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("C:/temp/weather.csv"), names=["city", "temperature", "date"]) 
df["temperature"].apply(np.round) #you just rounded the temperature column 
pd.to_csv('newfile.csv') # export to a new csv file
pd.to_xls('newfile.xls') # or export to an excel file instead
```

**DOS Batch**
A Batch script for this is much, much harder.  I will not write the whole program, because it is not a great solution.  But, I'll give you a taste in DOS batch code at the bottom of this post.  Compared to using Python or Excel, it is extremely complex.

Here is a rough *sketch* of DOS code.  Because I don't recommend this method, I didn't take the time to debug this code.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: prep our new file for output.  Let's write the header row.
echo col1, col2, col3 >newfile.csv
:: read the existing text file line by line
:: since it is csv, we will parse on comma
:: skip lines starting with semi-colon
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %%i in (input_file.txt) do (
    set col1=%%I, set col2=%%J, set col3=%%K
    :: truncate col2 to 1 decimal place
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%A in ("col2") do (
        set integer=%%A
        set "decimal=%%B
        set decimal=%decimal:~0,1%
        :: or, you can use an if statement to round up or down
        :: Now, put the integer and decimal together again and 
        :: redefine the value for col2.
        set col2=%integer%.%decimal%
        :: write output to a new csv file
        :: > and >> can redirect output from console to text file
        :: >newfile.csv will overwrite file.csv. We don't want 
        :: that, since we are in a loop.
        :: >>newfile.csv will append to file.csv, perfect!
        echo col1, col2, col3 >>newfile.csv
    )
)
:: open csv file in default application
start myfile.csv
```

Comment: You're a brave man attempting a batch demonstration.  +1 for the Excel and Python suggestions, even though your batch code floors instead of rounding.  (And someone might as well get a vote before the question is closed as too broad.)

Comment: Thanks rojo.  Rounding can be done, even though DOS does not like decimals.  
set %decimal%=%decimal:~0,1% 
(set /a %integer%=%integer%+1)

Comment: Thanks rojo.  Rounding can be done, even though DOS does not like decimals.  It adds a level of complexity that might be too confusing for a newbie.  If one wants the precision:
    :: read the first 2 decimal digits independently
    if "%decimal:~0,1%"=""  (
        set /a d1=0
    ) else (
        set /a d1=%decimal:~0,1%)
    if "%decimal:~1,2%"=""  (
        set /a d2=0
    ) else (
        set /a d2=%decimal:~1,2%)
    :: apply rounding 
    if %d2% gtr 4 (set /a d1+=1)
    if %d1% gtr 4 (set /a integer+=1)
    :: put the pieces together
    set col2=%integer%.%d1%%d2%